# Node.js no funciona método post cuando uso method-override y express-formidable

Tags: nodejs, express

He creado un CRUD usando "method-override" para actualizar una tabla imagen y me funcionó de maravillas. Luego, agregué la funcionalidad de subir imágenes usando "express-formidable" y funcionó de maravillas, pero cuando fui a validar el CRUD solo me funcionó el método GET y no el POST, PUT y el DELETE. Cuando comento las líneas de configuración de "express-formidable" nuevamente funciona el CRUD. ¿Alguna idea de que es lo que puede estar pasando? He llegado a pensar que estas dos librerías no son compatibles.

Mi configuración es la siguiente:

```js
var express =  require("express");
var pug = require('pug');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var User = require("./models/user").User;
var cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
var route_app = require("./routes_app");
var session_middleware = require("./middlewares/session");
var methodOverride = require("method-override")
var formidable = require("express-formidable")

var app = express();

app.set("views",__dirname+"/views");
app.set("view engine", "pug");

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use("/estatico",express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true})); 

app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

app.use(formidable({
    keepExtensions: true,
    allowEmptyFiles: true
}));
```